# DIY Kratky method hydroponics for growing Tomatoes using Milk Jugs

Tags: houseplants, vegetables, tomatoes, peppers, hydroponic

I want to make a small setup of non-circulating hydroponics by Kratky method for growing Tomatoes/peppers using Milk Jugs.
Due to COVID, I would like to get all the necessary items delivered home. So I chose Amazon.com.

- Budget: $50-100
- Number of plants: just for home needs so: 5-10 plants.
- Fertilizer: [MASTERBLEND 4-18-38 Complete Combo Kit Fertilizer Bulk
  (12.5 Pound Kit)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008OIRT7W)  $40
- Net slit pots: [50 2 Inch Net Slit Pots for
  Hydroponic Aeroponic Use](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008OIRT7W) $16
- Seeds: [Beefsteak Tomato Seeds - 250
  Seeds Non-GMO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013MASO6Q) $2
- Seedling starters:  [Seedling Starter Trays, 144
  Cells: (24 Trays; 6-Cells Per Tray), Plus 5 Plant Labels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0149L72CE) $9
- Growing Medium: I found three options

  1. [49 Rockwool Grow Cubes (1.5 Inches) - Growing Medium Starter Sheets (49 Per Pack)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IA8AJLO) $12
  2. [Organic Expanded Clay Pebbles Grow Media  2 LB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GN9A6LK) $18
  3. [General Hydroponics HGC714135 Rapid Rooter Plant Starters, 50 Plugs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002IU8K2)  $19
- Growing pots: used and sterilized 1 gallon Milk Jugs.

Total Price:  $79/85/86

What do you think about this setup? will this work? Am I missing something?
Are there any other cheaper/reliable options?

Comment: I've done lots of tomatoes in rockwhool and never used clay pebbles. You can save that money. 1 gal is fine to start the plants, but you will eventually need something bigger. 12.5 pounds is way more than you need.

Comment: Yes, I could not find something smaller.

Comment: But, do i need any other ingredients for tomatoes and peppers??

Comment: I used Geolite once, similar to clay pebbles.  You will need a full spectrum fertilizer because it is inert.  It has ZERO micronutrients.